# maven java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: postgresql, maven, dependencies, classnotfoundexception

I have added following dependency into maven's pom.xml file

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.0-801.jdbc4</version>
</dependency>
```

But it has not found the driver for the postgres database ?

Please describe me where is the problem.

Comment: Please explain how you run your app.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your repo don't have the requested jar. If so, add a repo tag to the pom.xml pointing to the jboss or maven repo.

```xml
<project ...>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
</project>
```

or

```xml
<project ...>
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>java.net</id>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>
</project>
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering but I got it solved as I was executing the Main class using "java -cp jarfile classfile" but the solution is to execute it with maven itself using "mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.app.Main"